# Most common words in English

Tags: data-request, nlp, english

I am looking for a machine readable data set (e.g., a mere txt file with one word per row) containing the X most common words in English, excluding proper nouns (unlike this [list](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/20k.txt)). If possible, ordered by frequency.

Comment: You can get the [top ten hundred words](https://xkcd.com/1133/) from http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/words.js ...I thought it had duplicates (I'm, I'd, I'll), but it looks like he has all contractions w/ two different types of apostrophes.

Comment: Because English capitalizes proper nouns and not all nouns, like German, it's fairly easy to do this with a few lines of code. This example does it for characters, but the switch to "words that don't start with a capital letter, except I" is easy enough http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7043/1511

Answer (score 6):

It's not entirely open but the best I've found in this vein is [www.wordfrequency.info](http://www.wordfrequency.info) - I am pretty sure that the 5000 word list is free, with fees for larger lists.

Answer (score 3):

There are word frequency lists for a number of languages, including English, that were created by Hermit Dave from the data at [opensubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org/de/de).

You can download them for free [on his blog](https://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/). The licence is: `Creative Commons – Attribution / ShareAlike 3.0 license`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also checkout this list at http://www.wordgamedictionary.com/word-lists/common-english-words/

Answer (score 2):

If you need more accurate and representative frequency counts of American English check out the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.wordfrequency.info/) which offers two different-length word lists (60k,100k) that include part-of-speech and frequency distribution across spoken and written registers of speech.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See resources at [Wiktionary:Frequency Lists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists)

In particular I have used [Leipzig Corpora Collection](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/). Use `cut -f2` if you just want the words and not the rank or frequency.