# French word list?

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary, french

I would like to make an auto-completion tool for people who are don't type very well, like what exists on phones. 
So I do not need just a dictionary but a list of all words, like all conjugations of verbs and all word variants (plural, gender). 
I can use use the [wiktionary's word frequency list](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Listes_de_fr%C3%A9quence), but it is not as complete as I would like. Yet, the frequency sorting property is interesting for me.

So should I look for something else or should I start with what I have?

Comment: Are any of [these answers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the perfect dataset for me: http://www.lexique.org/

Word are extracted from books and movies subtitles. It contains about 140,000 words.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just need all possible spellings, then I would suggest downloading Google N-Grams for N=1 (single words). These are individual words/strings coming from books in the French language. You also have the year, the count in that book, and the part of speech, if available. From this data you can create frequency lists of all unique spellings.

http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

[image]

The individual files are quite large. For example, a single file, `googlebooks-fre-all-1gram-20120701-a.gz` is 194 MB compressed, and 1.0 GB uncompressed. All full of single words.

The structure is quite simple

```
ngram TAB year TAB match_count TAB volume_count NEWLINE
```

So an actual line in the 1-gram files will look like this:

```
âutre_ADJ   1794    1   1
```

where _ADJ defines the part of speech.

License is [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

---

p.s. I'm a big fan of Python's [Collections library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for the task of counting frequency of something too large to read at once. See [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7043/1511) for example of counting characters. There is also a Python [N-gram downloader package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-ngram-downloader/), but in this case I prefer to get the files manually (since they are needed to be downloaded only once).

Comment: this dataset is very interesting. But too big for me. Sources seems also to not correspond with an everyday language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on this topic, but I believe that I have suggestion to make.

Start with the wiktionary word frequency list that is "not as complete as you would like," because it is still your best starting point.

Then find and fix the (occasional) "holes" after the fact.

Comment: It is what I have done, but this list was not as complete as it has to make my tool useful.

Answer (score 0):

https://grammalecte.net/ has a decent word list (over 450k words)

You can check the list at http://grammalecte.net:8080/file?name=lexicons/French.lex&ci=tip

Answer (score 0):

The project Wiktextract has extracted all words from Wiktionary, for the French words the English and French Wiktionary data is probably most interesting. Look here: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html and https://kaikki.org/dictionary/French/.

For word frequency filtering (should it be necessary) I can always recommend the wordfreq Python library, it also supports French.